# Video Grab error moving between Flask pages utilizing the same video stream

Tags: flask, video, yolov8

I am using YOLO video analysis and have two flask pages, the first shows the raw video stream and the second shows the stream with associated boxes from YOLO analysis. When i move through the flask page from the video stream page to the analysis page the video stream on both pages works. When i move back from the analysis page to the raw video stream page i get the following error

'CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -1072873821'

Code is as follows for YOLO analysis stream:

```
def yolo_stream():
    model = YOLO('yolo_training/foam_model.pt')
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_in_use)
    df_tank1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', 'name', 'name', 'name', 'name'])
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            df_tank1 = df_tank1.append({'date': datetime}, ignore_index=True)
            results = model(frame, show=False, conf=0.4, save=False)
            print (f'len of results: {(len(results))}')
            
            for r in results:
                boxes=r.boxes
                for box in boxes: 

                    # setting up the boxes in the video frames 
                    x1,y1,x2,y2=box.xyxy[0]
                    print('tensor coordinates of box: ', x1, y1, x2, y2) # prints tensors get it to print the integer box corners 
                    x1,y1,x2,y2=int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2)
                    print("int coordinates of  box: " ,x1,y1,x2,y2)  # this one should not show the tensor numbers, use this to get the area of the boxes which will then be graphed 
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (255,0,255),3)
                    conf=math.ceil((box.conf[0]*100))/100
                    cls=int(box.cls[0])
                    class_name=classNames[cls]
                    label=f'{class_name}{conf}'
                    area_in_box = (x2-x1)*(y2-y1) 
                    print(f'area in {class_name} box: ', area_in_box)
                    t_size = cv2.getTextSize(label, 0, fontScale=1, thickness=2)[0]
                    c2 = x1 + t_size[0], y1 - t_size[1] - 3
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1,y1), c2, [255,0,255], -1, cv2.LINE_AA)  # filled
                    cv2.putText(frame, label, (x1,y1-2),0, 1,[255,255,255], thickness=1,lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)

                    # creating the graph and a pd data frame for holding the box values and adds values 
                    if area_in_box:
                        df_tank1 = df_tank1.append({class_name: int(area_in_box)}, ignore_index=True) # functional with readouts in cmd 
                    

                # actual generation of the frame on the page 
                ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
                frame = buffer.tobytes()    
                yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                    b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n'            )
           
        else:
            break
    cap.release()
```

code for raw video stream:

```
def generate_frames():
    while True:
        success, frame = cap.read()
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            # dipslaying the frame 
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
```